# Can't get multiple flexbox children to position or center

Tags: html, css

A short JSfiddle to demonstrate my problem [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2xup0ce9/3/).

My objectives are:

1. The date should be centered both horizontally and vertically in its rectangle.
2. The subtitle should be below the title.

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: pink;
}

.date {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="date">Apr<br>01</div>
    <h3>
      Blog Title
    </h3>
    <p>
      Subtitle - should be below title
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="date">Mar<br>01</div>
    <h3>
      Another Blog Title
    </h3>
    <p>
      Subtitle - should be below title
    </p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use flexbox a lot but with divs mostly. Using other HTML elements is valuable for me, when there are preset styles for them for the whole application, then it is easier :)

Here is how I would do this (CSS explained under snippet):

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.date {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="date">
    <div>Apr</div>
    <div>01</div>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="title">Another Blog Title</div>
    <div>Subtitle - should be below title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1) .container

- **display: inline-flex** -> date and info text items are inline
- **width: 100%** -> fit parent width.. can be set fixed to 300px for example

2) .date & .info

- **display: flex** -> using flexbox, not inline. Make other flexbox CSS properties works and adds own adjustments
- **flex-direction: column** -> this makes children align under each other (into column)
- **align-items: center** -> when flex-direction is active this will align children horizontaly, otherwise vertically
- **justify-content: center** -> when flex-direction is active, this will align children vertically, otherwise horizontally

As for your snippet, just adjust it this way:

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: pink;
}

.date {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0px;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="date">Apr<br>01</div>
    <div class="info">
      <h3>
        Blog Title
      </h3>
      <p>
        Subtitle - should be below title
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="date">Mar<br>01</div>
    <div class="info">
      <h3>
        Another Blog Title
      </h3>
      <p>
        Subtitle - should be below title
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Explanation of this CSS is under the first snippet. I just removed margins from **h3** and **p** elements, so it does not break layout :)

Hope it helps you.

I learned a lot of flexbox from this article -> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

Give it a try and GL ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. To center contents of `.date` on both directions you can use flexbox:

```css
.date {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center; /* centers vertically */
  justify-content: center; /* centers horizontally */
}
```

2. To display the `<h3>` above the `<p>` you could give them a wrapper with:

```css
.date + div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start; /* align children to left side */
  justify-content: center; /* center vertically */
}
```

You might also want to remove the margins on the `<h3>`s and `<p>`s;

```css
.date + div > * {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: pink;
}

.date {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.date + div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
}
.date + div > * {
  margin: 0;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="date">Apr<br>01</div>
    <div>
      <h3>
        Blog Title
      </h3>
      <p>
        Subtitle - should be below title
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="date">Mar<br>01</div>
    <div>
      <h3>
        Another Blog Title
      </h3>
      <p>
        Subtitle - should be below title
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**Important note:** You might notice `align-items` and `justify-content`s refer to different directions when used on first, respectively the second child of your `<li>`s. That's because they're dependent on the `flex-direction`, as follows:

- `justify-content` controls alignment on the direction of `flex-direction`
- `align-items` controls alignment on the direction perpendicular on `flex-direction`
- default `flex-direction` value is `row`

Answer (score 2):

> 1. The date should be centred both horizontally and vertically in its rectangle.

```
.date {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
```

Using Flexbox, you can just add `justify-content: center` for horizontal and `align-items: center` for vertical alignments. But you'd need to set the `display:flex` first.

> 2. The subtitle should be below the title.

For this, you can set the `display` to flex and use the `flex-direction` on the main container, in this case it'll be your ordered list `<ol>` element. Then update the `<li>` element to also use flex and

```
ol {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
li {
  flex: 1;
  flex: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see below. I documented the changes in the source.

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: pink;
}

.date {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: flex; /* Added */
  align-items: center; /* Added */
  justify-content: center; /* Added */
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
}


/* Added */

.titles h3 {
  margin: 0.5rem 0 0 0;
}


/* Added */

.titles p {
  margin: 0.5rem 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="date">Apr<br>01</div>
    <!-- Extra wrapper added -->
    <div class="titles">
      <h3>
        Blog Title
      </h3>
      <p>
        Subtitle - should be below title
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="date">Mar<br>01</div>
    <!-- Extra wrapper added -->
    <div class="titles">
      <h3>
        Another Blog Title
      </h3>
      <p>
        Subtitle - should be below title
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ol/ul li` elements when you want to define an ordered/unordered list of elements, for example a navigation bar. What you are doing now is not semantically correct.

Take a look at: [float and clear properties](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/float/).

I rewrited your code using float and clear properties. In order to center the date, since it is a static content, just remove the height property and add a padding for create your margins. At last, instead of using `float: right` for your content, I used [display flex properties](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#preview {
  background-color: pink;
}

#preview .group {
  display: flex;
}

.date {
  float: left;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 5px;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.content h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

.content p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="preview">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="date">Apr<br>01</div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Blog title</h3>
      <p>Subtitle - should be below title</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="date">Mar<br>01</div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Another Blog title</h3>
      <p>Subtitle - should be below title</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```